# The spell temper (old card) effect in combat damage resolution

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Temper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5251) prevents the next 'X' damage and puts 'X' +1/+1 counters on a creature.  Do those counters increase the damage done by this creature in the combat resolution step?
Also how does it interact with an '[Nomads en-Kor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNomads%20en-Kor%5d)' style damage redirection or a [Boros Reckoner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoros%20Reckoner%5d)?

Answer (score 5):

Okay there's two questions here so lets take them one at a time. First though being combat damage only matters for the timing of the damage in the first question, Temper works the same way regardless of how the damage is dealt.

1) [Temper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5251) will NOT change the damage done by that creature in the same damage step, damage is already assigned in full, and would have been dealt at the same time it was to take the damage being prevented. Making a creature more powerful after damage is assigned doesn't change that. If however the damage prevented was from a first strike source, and your creature does not have first strike, or has double strike, the second damage step will have those counters and will do that extra damage. This is seen more recently with the effect of [Drana, Liberator of Malakir](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDrana%2c%20Liberator%20of%20Malakir%5d) every time she hits all attacking creatures get a +1/+1 counter, and she has first strike.

2) If Temper was placed on [Boros Reckoner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoros%20Reckoner%5d), his effect will not be triggered, he was dealt no damage so his effect does nothing. The [en-Kor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%20[en-kor]) redirection effects could go either way, assuming one player controls both the effects that player chooses which one applies first and which tries to apply second. The one that would apply second fails to happen, because damage is no longer going to be dealt to that creature. This is covered in the [Comprehensive rules](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Interaction_of_replacement_and/or_prevention_effects):

> **616.1** If two or more replacement and/or prevention effects are attempting to modify the way an event affects an object or player, the affected object's controller (or its owner if it has no controller) or the affected player chooses one to apply, following the steps listed below. If two or more players have to make these choices at the same time, choices are made in APNAP order (see rule 101.4).

If Temper is cast on the creature that damage is being redirected to, both effects will apply, the damage will be redirected and then prevented.

It's worth noting that Temper still prevents X damage during that turn, unlike some other sources it does not care from where or when the damage is dealt, beyond that it is all in that one turn. So if you redirect all damage from a group of en-Kor creatures being hit by something like [pyroclasm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bpyroclasm%5d) it will prevent all of up to X of that damage, and if anything is left be able to prevent still more later in the turn.

Comment: You might want to clarify why Temper can prevent more than 1 point of damage if cast on the creature that en-Kor redirected to.

Comment: @Taemyr Fair enough, I added in that number of sources doesn't matter, though that part should be obvious. More important was to fix that they have an option on the en-Kor/replacement effects.

Comment: I haven't played MtG in ages, so on reading en-Kor thought that you could only prevent one damage.  Then read your answer and rethought, because I would have no problem with Temper preventing damage from multiple completely different sources - then I tried to find the rules that applies, but struggle a bit with that because prevention effects is a continous effect; so how long does a continous effect from an instant last?  All in all I think I am beyond the scope of the question though.

Comment: @Taemyr you can activate the ability as many times as you can afford, and since the en-Kor effect has a cost of 0, that's infinite. It just redirect the first point with the first one, then the next point is the first one again and it gets redirected also.

Comment: @Taemyr as for how long it lasts, the oracle text for Temper says "
Prevent the next X damage that would be dealt to target creature this turn. For each 1 damage prevented this way, put a +1/+1 counter on that creature." IT lasts to the end of the turn.

Comment: Yes, the oracle text is way clearer. - IIUC, without the oracle text the effect would remain until the spell had prevented the full X amount, even across subsequent turns.  (By 611.2a)